# Duplicate Entry on OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
 @Component
    @Entity
    public class Parent {

        private Long id;

        private List<Child> reviews = new ArrayList<Child>();

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @OrderBy("commentRating DESC")
        public List<Child> getchildren() {
            return children;
        }


        public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }

        public void addChild() {
            getChildren().add(new Child(this.id));

        }

    }


    @Component
    @Entity
    public class Child {

        private List<ChildChild> children = new ArrayList<ChildChild>();

        private long id;

            private long parent_Id;

        public Child(){}

        public Child(long parentId) {
                this.parentId = parentId;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

            public long getParentId() {
               return parentId;
            }

            public void setParentId(long parentId) {
               this.parentId = parentId;
            }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @IndexColumn(name="IDX")
        public List<ChildChild> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        public void setChildren(List<ChildChild> children) {
            this.chidren = children;
        }

        public void addChild(String userName, String text) {
            getChildren().add(new ChildChild(userName, text));
        }

    }

    @Component
    @Entity
    public class ChildChild {

        private String userName;
        private String text;
        private long id;

        public ChildChild() {

        }

        public ChildChild(String userName, String text) {
            setUserName(userName);
            setText(text);
        }

        @Column(columnDefinition="LONGTEXT")
        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }
```

After I add more than one ChildChild to any Child and then try to add a new Parent I get a Duplicate Entry '' for key 'childs_id' on the table Parent_id, childs_id.

With just one ChildChild on any child it's fine.

Am I making some kind of conceptual error here?

Stack Trace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myProgram] in context with path [/myProgram] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'childs_id'; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'childs_id'] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'childss_id'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1210)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:554)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.addChild(Unknown Source)
    at controllers.myProgram.addChild(myProgram.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Comment: Please make the obove code compile, post the code that you're executing, and the complete stack trace of the exception you get. What's the parent_id field in Child for?

Comment: your entire `Child` class is wrong. I don't see `parentId`,`chidren` defined any where. Also getter/setters are wrong for `children`, my eyes are really sore!

Comment: I've changed the names of the classes to try to make it more clear. I meant ChildChild, not child for the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
public void addChild() {
    getReviews().add(new Review(this.id)); 
}
```

I guess, it should be `new Child(this.id)`?

The proper way is to 1) create a `ChildChild`, 2) persist it so that the ID are initialized, 3) add it to `Child`. The same is true for adding `Child` to `Parent`.

Comment: But I have no problem adding as Many Child as I want. Only when I add more than one ChildChild to any Child does the error occur. How would this explain that behaviour?

Comment: By persisting the `ChildChild` upfront, the ID's of the list items are (properly) set and different for all items in the list. Perhaps this behaviour is vendor specific.

Comment: If that is so then why do I only get an error when I add more than one ChildChild to Child?

Answer (score 0):

You should tell Hibernate what are you using for your mapping in your OneToMany annotation in the parent. For example,

```
OneToMany(mappedBy="child")
```

Also, instead of referencing the parent_id in the child class, you should try to reference the parent entity object in the child class.

```
public void addChild() {
        getChildren().add(new Child(this));
}
```

and your child will have a Parent field.

```
private Parent parent;
```

Comment: Why would the lack of mappedBy be causing this behavior? Putting a reference to the parent in the child class defeats the object of using Hibernate in the first place doesn't it?

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. Its not a question of "Why use hibernate" but "how to use hibernate". Hibernate requires you to provide a column which will define the mapping column